# JQueryUI accordion broken in IE7 when embedded in parent container with overflow:auto set

Tags: internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-accordion, css

The JQuery UI Accordion widget doesn't work with longer scrollable content in IE7 when **any** parent container div has `overflow:auto;` set on it. I tried setting the innermost child div of the Accordion to `overflow:visible !important;` but it didn't work. Works fine in IE8, IE9, IE9 compatibility mode, Chrome, FF, Opera, and Safari.

[Test this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/johntrepreneur/wPTRC/10/) in IE7. Be sure to explicity set IE to use "Browser mode: IE7" and "Document Mode: IE7 standards".

How to fix?

```
<div style="overflow:auto;">
  <div id="accordion" style="overflow:visible;float:right;height:400px;width:500px;border:2px solid red;float:right;">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
        document.write("<p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>");
        document.write("<ul>");
        document.write("<li>List item one</li>");
        document.write("<li>List item two</li>");
        document.write("<li>List item three</li>");
        document.write("</ul>");
        }
      </script>
        </div>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
          <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it's a bug in the current version of jqueryui accordion. 
See the [jqueryui bug report here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8977).

Comment: If it helps, I ended up changing the CSS of the parent container to make it behave as expected. It was either just a change to `overflow` and/or the `position` style(s). That was quicker than fixing/patching the accordion bug.